# nesting brace expansion and command substitution

Tags: bash, ls, seq

I want to create a simple bash-script that checks whether a directory contains all the files whose names contain numbers from 1 to N.

```
# Creating some files for testing
$ cd /tmp/
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/a01x.dat
$ touch test/b02y.dat

# Display dir contents
$ ls test/*{01,02}*
test/a01x.dat  test/b02y.dat
```

But using `seq` command to generate numbers results in the following:

```
$ ls test/*{$(seq -s , -f "%02g" 1 2)}*
ls: cannot access 'test/*{01,02}*': No such file or directory
```

I understand that running the command by surrounding the path with single quotation marks must lead to the error because the wildcards don't expand

```
$ ls 'test/*{01,02}*'
```

But I didn't use them. What is the problem?

Comment: "check whether a directory contains all the files" - do you want to do something if a file doesn't exist with that number in it?  Or do you just want to show files that contain one of those numbers as part of the file name (your `ls test/*{01,02}*` seems to indicate so...) ? Also, what format will the numbers be in? If N=100 will you use 001 or 1 or ?? to start?

Comment: @ivanivan I've renamed the question

Comment: The `cannot access` error message from `ls` always shows the name in question surrounded with quotes, that has nothing to do with your problem. It might depend on the version of `ls`, though. Try something like `ls foo "foo "`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the shell will do brace expansion (which processes `{...,...}`) before it does command substitution (the `$(...)` part.) So after your `seq` is expanded, the shell will not re-evaluate the `{01,02}` and will leave it as a literal.

You need to add an `eval` to have it re-evaluate the expression after the command substitution is performed:

```
$ eval "ls test/*{$(seq -s , -f "%02g" 1 2)}*"
```

In this case, the command substitution will be performed first, resulting in a string `ls test/*{01,02}*` and the `eval` will ask the shell to interpret this as a command, which will then perform the brace and glob expansion, resulting in the list of files you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this, but for an unknown reason didn't test it.