# Why does this rsync call not work properly?

Tags: bash, rsync, brace-expansion

I made a simple script to perform backup of my NAS. I do it as follows:

```
date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
base="/backup"
newest="$(ls -1td "$base"/*-*-*/ | head -n 1)"
today="$base/$date"
dirs="pub,data,software"

if [ -d "$today" ]; then
  echo "Backup already exists"
  exit 1
fi

echo $newest
echo $dirs

mkdir "$today"
rsync -a --delete --info=progress2 "/myzpool/{$dirs}" "$today" --link-dest="$newest"
```

So what it is supposed to do is to create a folder with the name of the current date and then copy the folders `/myzpool/pub`, `/myzpool/data` and `/myzpool/software` into this newly created backup folder. But surprisingly, this does not work! `rsync` aborts with the error `rsync: link_stat "/myzpool/{pub,data,software}" failed: No such file or directory`.

I don't understand why this happens, because I use a very similar script to backup my virtual server via SSH:

```
dirs="srv,opt,home,root,etc"
mkdir "$today"
rsync -caz --compress-level=9 -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/myserver.conf" --delete --info=progress2 "root@myserver.tld:/{$dirs}" "$today" --link-dest="$newest"
```

and with the virtual server it works just fine. So what is the difference between the two command lines, and how could I fix my script, such that it also works locally?

Comment: Brace expansion does not happen within double quotes.

Comment: So why then does it work when backing up my virtual web server via rsync + ssh?

Comment: In the `bash` shell, `"{$dirs}"` would expand to `"{srv,opt,home,root,etc}"`. As far as I know, `rsync` would then try to access that as the literal name of the file to sync. `rsync` does no special processing of curly braces.  There are examples of using brace expansions in the `rsync` manual, but those examples relies on the shell to do the expansion, and `bash` simply won't expand `{$dirs}` like you'd want due to the order in which expansions happens (brace expansions happen before variable expansions).

Comment: I understand that the braces are expanded as you described, this is clear. But I still don't understand why I then `"root@myserver.tld:/{$dirs}" ` is valid, while `"/myzpool/{$dirs}"` isn't. In both cases the brace expansion happens, but `rsync` doesn't accept the first command line (copying local files), while it does accept the latter (copying from a remote server).

Comment: Quoted brace expensing works for `rsync` in this case because there is another level of shell evaluation - on the remote server.

Answer (score -2):

I just had a similar problem and have determined that Brace Expansion **does** work inside Command Substitution.

The problem is that Brace Expansion occurs before anything else so the `rsync` needs to be run like `eval rsync ...` so that the Brace Expansion is done a second time.

See [this answer for more details...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476741/27437)